# testing useEffect in react testing library + jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

**the goal**

I am trying to test that useEffect function that changes the text of a follow button to unfollow after he have been clicked

**the result**

when i test the component the follow/unfollow action is getting dispatched but the text of the button is not changing

**explanation of the login inside the useEffect function**

The way it hapeens is that after clicking the follow button a follow/unfollow action is dispatched and add the who got followed (userToFollow) to the logged user following accounts array (loggedUserData.following), and then changes the button text to unfollow and vice verca.

**my 2 cents on why the test is failing**

I suppose that the problem lays in the fact that i mocked the follow/unfollow action therefore it's just getting called and not resolved the way its should, if I could add the user that have been followed to the list of the logged user following accounts the problem should be solved.

anyone has an idea how can I do it or offer a better idea to solve it?

**SOLUTION**
so the problem was that redux-mock-store doesnt approve updating state so I've rendered the tests with real the redux Store and everything works

**load logged user data action**

```
export const loadloggedUserDataAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
            },
        };
        const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/accounts/logged_user/`, config);

        dispatch({ type: GET_LOGGED_USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: res.data 
});
        console.log(res.data); 
/* 
res.data = data: {
                id: 'id',
                name: 'name',
                email: 'email',
                following: [userToFollow],
                followers: [userToFollow],
            },
*/
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: GET_LOGGED_USER_DETAILS_FAIL });
    }
};
```

**the error**

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button" and name "unfollow"
```

**the test**

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    post: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
            data: {
                id: 'id',
                name: 'name',
                email: 'email',
                following: [userToFollow],
                followers: [userToFollow],
            },
        }),
    get: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
            data: {
                id: 'id',
                name: 'name',
                email: 'email',
                following: [userToFollow],
                followers: [userToFollow],
            },
        }),
}));


const userToFollow = 'userId';
const loggedUserData = {
    id: 'id',
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email',
    following: [],
    followers: [],
};
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
const initialState = {
    userReducer: { isUserAuthenticated: true, loggedUserData: loggedUserData },
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);

describe('FollowUnFollow - isUserAlreadyFollowed false', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <FollowUnFollow userToFollow={userToFollow} />
            </Provider>
        );
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        cleanup();
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });
    test('follow button should dispatch followUnFollowAction ',async () => {
        const followButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'follow' });
        userEvent.click(followButton);
       

        const unFollowButton = await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'unfollow' });
        expect(unFollowButton).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

**the component**

```js
const FollowUnFollow = ({ userToFollow }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [button, setButton] = useState('follow');
    const { loggedUserData, isUserAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);
console.log(loggedUserData) 
/*
loggedUserData ===
{
                id: 'id',
                name: 'name',
                email: 'email',
                following: [],
                followers: [],
            }
*/
    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            const isUserAlreadyFollowed = loggedUserData?.following.includes(userToFollow);
            if (isUserAlreadyFollowed) {
                setButton('unfollow');
            } else {
                setButton('follow');
            }
        } catch {}
    }, [dispatch, loggedUserData, userToFollow]);
    
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            dispatch(followUnFollowAction({ user_to_follow: userToFollow }));
        } catch {}
    };

    const authLinks = (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <button>{button}</button>
        </form>
    );

    return <div data-testid='followUnFollow'>{isUserAuthenticated ? <div>{authLinks}</div> : null}</div>;
};

export default FollowUnFollow;
```

**the follow action**

```
export const followUnFollowAction =
    ({ user_to_follow }) =>
    async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                },
            };
            const body = JSON.stringify({ user_to_follow });
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/followers/follow/`, body, config);
            dispatch({ type: FOLLOW_UNFOLLOW_USER_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
            dispatch(loadUserDetailsAction({ id: user_to_follow }));
            dispatch(loadloggedUserDataAction());
        } catch {
            dispatch({ type: FOLLOW_UNFOLLOW_USER_FAIL });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario it looks that you want to simply spy on the `followUnFollowAction` function and mock the axios library post method so it returns what your component expects:

In your test:

```
(delete the mock for `jest.mock('../../../redux/actions/follower')`)

import * as follower from '../../../redux/actions/follower';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  default: {
    post: () => Promise.resolve({
      data: *data that you want to send to the FOLLOW_UNFOLLOW_USER_SUCCESS action*
    })
  }
}))

...

test('follow button should dispatch followUnFollowAction ', () => {
  const followUnFollowActionSpy = jest.spy(follower, 'followUnFollowAction');

...

const timesActionHaveDispatched = followUnFollowActionSpy.mock.calls.length;
        expect(timesActionHaveDispatched).toBe(1);
        expect(followUnFollowActionSpy.mock.calls[0][0].user_to_follow).toBe(userToFollow);

...
```

Additionally when testing for a state change I would recommend to use `findBy` instead of `getBy` as `findBy` returns a promise and will wait for the changes to get committed to the "DOM" (jsdom when testing) like:

```
test('follow button should dispatch followUnFollowAction ', async () => {

...

const unFollowButton = await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'unfollow' });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,  I've tried it yet still the same error arise. the mock didnt update the state data. the array loggedUserData.following is still empty

Comment: i have updated the question, added the action.tsx code if it can help you can check it out

Comment: Updated the solution to use a spy instead, so `followUnFollowAction` is not mocked

Comment: the followUnFollowAction is failing and enter the catch block instead of the updating the reducer state. is there any way to force the action to succeed? or updating the state manually inside the test should also do the trick

Comment: yes now that the real `followUnFollowAction ` function is used, your axios.post request is failing, you'll need to mock the axios library so you can control what the axios.post returns, I updated my answer

Comment: updated the `axios` mock as axios default export is usually used like
`import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235517/discussion-between-maxletou-and-eliyamelamed).

Comment: I've switched from using redux-mock-store to the real redux store and everything works thanks for your time